# MISRA 5.2 rule : confusion

Tags: c, misra

I am getting MISRA 5.2 rule violation in my project. The code for which i am getting violation is a structure that is declared as extern in one header file. The code example is as under

1.h

```
extern struct con tmp_ev;
```

2.c

```
struct con tmp_ev;
cioF_get(&tmp_ev);
```

3.c

```
struct con tmp_ev;
 (void)eeF_read(CON, &tmp_ev);
```

I get the warning only in 2.c in the line `struct con tmp_ev;` saying that

> declaration of symbol tmp_ev hides symbol tmp_ev

and not in 3.c . Both 2.c and 3.c include the 1.h header file.

I am confused why this issue is present. Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: You have two distinct variables with the same name.  Delete one of them so neither your Misra checker nor the linker has to complain about it.

Comment: The use of `extern`/spaghetti programming is fishy in the first place, MISRA or no MISRA.

Comment: @Lundin: I need to use the variable in different files and so i had used it as an extern in the header file. If still there is something wrong in my code then please tell me as i am new to it and might have done something in a wrong way

Comment: @AnkitShah That's why we use setters/getters. The use of `extern` is what's wrong with your code. There's very few exceptions when it is acceptable to use, basically only when using `const` variables.

Answer (score 4):

The rule 5.2 is stating that a variable in local scope should not hide the global one with the same name

You have local variable with name `tmp_ev` and a global variable with the same name. The local one is shadowing the global one. Rename either the local ones or the global one.

Comment: I think you are right but now the quesition is that i am having 2 local variables with the same name in different files. So , tool should show an warning of MISRA 5.2 violation there also. But it is not showing there. It is showing only in one file. both the files include the header file

Any idea what might the reason behind that??

Comment: That's something about the tool itself. Maybe it is set not to report the same violation on a same global more than once. Just a speculation. Rename one of these and see if it will start to complain about the second one.

Comment: I renamed the local variable and build the project and then performed the check and now it works without any violations. 

For the other file , i will call the tool vendor to ask him about that.

Thank you for your answer

Comment: @AnkitShah Many static analyser tools behave crappily when faced with more than one .c file. Also, the old MISRA-C:2004 had some strange rules here that have been remade or removed in MISRA-C:2012. I would advise upgrading to the latter, since the identifier chapter of MISRA-C:2004 was rather poor.

Answer (score 4):

You should learn the difference between "declaration" and "definition" of
C-objects. There may only be one "definition" of an object but arbitrarily many "declararions". A "declaration" is a mere statment that an object exists. A "definiton" establishes that existence. `extern` is always a declaration of an object somewhere else (or "here") and never a "definition".

A declaration `Type variable;` without `extern` in a C-file always produces 
a definition (called "tentative defintion") of `variable` in its C-file.

I am not that familiar with misra (currently learning it myself)
but your architecture is messy:

File `1.h` *declares* one extern `tmp_ev` with global scope.

File `2.c` *defines* a variable `tmp_ev` with global scope. (a "tentative definition").

File `3.c` *defines* yet another variable `tmp_ev` (again a "tentative definition") also with global scope.

So the two definitions of `tmp_ev` in the C-files compete. You should now decide which C-file (alias "compilation unit") is entitled to *define* `tmp_env`. All other C-files should use the `extern` *declaration*, preferably by `#include "1.h"`.

Note that a C-file may "declare" a variable it "defines". It is a common idiom among C-programmers to *declare* a variable `foo_var` in some header `foo.h` and *define* it in an associated C-file named `foo.c` which itself includes `foo.h`.

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet provided should not generate a MISRA-C:2004 Rule 5.2 violation as there is not a nesting of an inner scope and an outer scope.

However, this IS a violation of MISRA-C:2004 Rule 8.9 as you have two (tentative) definitions of `tmp_ev` at global scope.

Note: also being discussed on the ["official" MISRA Forum](https://www.misra.org.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=61&t=1715) and has generated the following reply:

> Rule 5.2 only applies to identifiers in inner scopes. It is unclear from the example whether the code in 2.c and 3.c exists at file scope or within a function.
>
> If "struct con tmp_ev" in 2.c and 3.c appears within a function definition there will be a violation of rule 5.2.
>
> If "struct con tmp_ev" appears at file scope, there is a violation of rule 8.9 as there are two (tentative) definitions of "struct con tmp_ev" in the project.